# Enforcing unique combinations of fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

There is a model which could have multiple items linked to it, like:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class MyModelItem(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'A NAME'),
        ('B', 'B NAME'),
        ('C', 'C NAME')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name='items')
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The requirement is: for each record of `MyModel`, don't allow more than one record of `MyModelItem` which has the same `item_type`, which means if I have:

```
from myproj.myapp.models import MyModel, MyModelItem

m1 = MyModel.objects.create(name='M1')

MyModelItem.objects.create(name='Item1', model=m1, item_type='A')
```

then I can't add another record with the same type 'A' to `m1`.

One solution for me is doing it like this within `MyModelItem`:

```
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.model.items.filter(item_type=self.item_type):
            raise IntegrityError("%s already have a item with type %s" % (self.model, self.item_type))
        super(MyModelItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but this won't protect the limitation on the db level. It's possible to add such not-allowed records with SQL directly, and it can break my application. Is there an approach to implement this requirement in Django? Something like `unique_together`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it, `unique_together` is the way to do this. It's as simple as:

```
class MyModelItem(models.Model): 
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name='items')
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('model', 'item_type')
```

Comment: I can't recall why I was thinking 'unique_together' can't fulfill my requirement, so stupid. Thanks for your answer and your updates to my question to correct my poor English.

Comment: Worth noting that firstly one needs to migrate and only then add the `unique_together` constraint and run migration again.